# Quadratic equation geometry word problem - lowest value

Tags: quadratics

I have a question that has two parts:

[image: Question]

The first part is relatively straightforward, this is my approach to part a:

[image: My approach to part a]

However, for part b, I am unsure as to how to approach the problem. I can see that the resulting equation for the area of the sum of the two areas is a quadratic and perhaps finding the minimum value vertex of the function would arrive at the value for x and area. However, I am unsure as to how to go about that. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can use Calculus to answer the second part. Take the first derivative, Take the 2nd derivative and solve for x.

Comment: see:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wjz-jbOCvYQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question could be done fairly easily with calculus but let's take a purely alebraic approach. First write your expression as $ax^2+bx+c.$ Note that $a>0.$  Then we take out the factor $a$ and complete the square. In detail, $$ax^2+bx+c=a(x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{c}{a})$$ $$=a((x+\frac{b}{2a})^2-\frac{b^2}{4a^2}+\frac{c}{a})$$ $$=a((x+\frac{b}{2a})^2+(\frac{-b^2+4ac}{4a^2}))$$ $$=a(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2+(\frac{-b^2+4ac}{4a})$$ The term $a(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2\ge0$ and is 0 iff $x=-\frac{b}{2a}$. Thus your wloe expression has minimum value $$\frac{-b^2+4ac}{4a}$$ and this minimum value occurs when $x=-\frac{b}{2a}$.

Comment: So essentially rewrite my jumbled up quadratic into standard form, then use x = -b/2a to find minimum value and area?